# How can I model the relationship of a college and students/lecturers with Python and mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to create a model of a college, the college has a name, a founded date, it has a list of students/lecturers etc..

Should I just have one class called college and have the students as a list inside that class, or should I create new classes for student and lecturer and somehow use them inside the college class.

I am new to programming so I am sorry if this is a noob question, however I am not sure what is possible with Python and do not know how to phrase this better.

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend you go the object oriented route. This would allow for more expansive code that adds functionality to your program such as attributes for your classes (i.e. Student, Lecturer, College, ...etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example structure could be something like this:

```py
class College:
    def __init__(self, name, established_date):
        # Set attributes for your College

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, major):
        # Set attributes for specific student

class Lecturer:
    def __init__(self, name, courses):
        # Set attributes for specific lecturer
```

And inside your `College` class, you can create a list of `Student` or `Lecturer` objects that still retain their attributes you can access later.

```
class College:
    def __init__(self, name, students, lecturers):
        self.name = name
        self.students = students  # List of Student objects
        self.lecturers= lecturers # List of Lecturer objects
```

You can then mirror this model for your database (or vice-versa) to make it easy to insert/retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a db design question.
I would have done the following:
Create a collection/table/model for each object i.e: college, students, class.

College will have 1 line in the table (one document in the collection), with college name + date.
Students will have a document for each student, which will contain Student's attributes + two foreign keys: one for college and the other for class (college might be redundant as you can acquire it from the Class model).
Class model will have entry for it's attributes (name, level, date, etc...) + foreign key for the college document.

This is merely a suggestion though, and there is more than one correct answer depends on usage and implementation.

So that will be:

```
class College:
def __init__(self, name, date):
    self.name = name
    self.date = date


class Student:
def __init__(self, name, id, ..., classes_fk):
    self.name = name
    .
    .
    .
    self.classes = classes_fk # list of foreign keys to class collection

class CollegeClass:
def __init__(self, name, date, college_fk):
    .
    .
    .
    self.college_fk = college_fk # foreign key for college collection
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a homework question. 
I would suggest going through `4.2  Ex: Superclass Person and its subclasses`
in the following article [OOP Concepts](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3f_OOPExercises.html)